# I want to know the date when i installed hyper-v

Tags: windows-8.1, vmware-workstation, hyper-v

because i want to restore my pc as i can't remove hyper-v in windows 8.1 pro

i have tried by

1. disabling from windows features                  ---did not work
2. using dism from cmd as admin                     ---did not work
3. using powershell as admin                         ---did not work

after trying each of these when pc reboots it ultimately says "windows couldn't complete features        ......undoing changes"

i am with this problem from many days now, due to this I am unable to use VMware Workstation.

Comment: Did you check System restore Wizard ? It lists changes made in computer with information like Date & Time, Description, Type etc..

Comment: Event Viewer may contain information about when the Hyper-V role was enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Creation Date/Time of this folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Hyper-V
```

it has created when Hyper-V was installed.